# Can we get a Global Maxima by using EM algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization

Actually, I read many articles and blogs that EM converges to local maxima can someone help me that it converges to local maxima always? Can we get a global maximum?

Comment: Are you asking if it can ever happen? Because there are trivial answers: if there is only global maxima and no local ones, or by chance.

Comment: Actually I want to know can you give me some examples or proof where we can find Global maxima by using EM algorithm?

Comment: One more question can we proof or guaranteed say that EM always converge to a local maxima?